# Recursive nesting typings with selected properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript4.0

So I have the following interfaces & types:

```js
interface A {
    A(): void;
}

interface B {
    B(): void;
}

interface C {
    C(): void;
}

type All = A & B & C;
```

and i want to extract a partial set of the methods AND create another nesting level which can do the same thing recursively: [typescript version 4.1.0]

```js
type SelectMethods<
    METHODS extends Partial<All>, 
    MORE extends Record<string, SelectMethods<any>> = {}
> = Pick<All, Extract<keyof All, keyof METHODS>> & MORE;
```

- Taking a partial set of `All`
- Picking only the relevant selected methods
- Merging it with a `Record` that for each property do the same

this allows me to do the following, **which works great**:

```js
const obj: SelectMethods<A & B, { x: SelectMethods<A & B & C> }> = {
    A() {
    },
    B() {
    },
    x: {
        A() {
        },
        B() {
        },
        C() {
        }
    }
};
```

But when removing the `C` (or any of the others) in the inner `SelectMethods` it **stop working**:
[error appears for the type literal between the stars]

```js
const obj: SelectMethods<A & B, **{ x: SelectMethods<A & B> }**> = {  // Property 'C' is missing in type 'Pick<All, "A" | "B">' but required in type 'Pick<All, "A" | "B" | "C">'.
    A() {
    },
    B() {
    },
    x: {
        A() {
        },
        B() {
        }
    }
};
```

things i've tries so far:

- conditional types to try proving to the compiler it's ok:

```js
type SelectMethods<METHODS extends Partial<All>, MORE extends Record<string, SelectMethods<any>> = {}> =
    Pick<All, Extract<keyof All, keyof METHODS>> & (
        MORE extends Record<string, infer DEEP> ?
            DEEP extends SelectMethods<infer SUBMETHODS> ? 
                SUBMETHODS extends Partial<All> ?
                    MORE
                    : never
                : never
            : never
    );
```

but i'm getting `TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.`

any ideas? :)

Comment: Could you add more usage examples? The example above can be just `const obj: A & B & { x: A & B & C } = ...` without any complicated definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with

```
Pick<All, Extract<keyof All, keyof METHODS>>
```

Let's make that it's own type so that we can play with it:

```
type MethodPick<METHODS extends Partial<All>> = Pick<All, Extract<keyof All, keyof METHODS>>
```

This works fine on the first level.  `type AB = MethodPick<A & B>` is just A & B.

But what is the actual type of `SelectMethods<any>` aka `SelectMethods<Partial<All>>`?  You might think that it would be a partial selection of methods, but it's not.  It actually requires that A, B, and C are all set. This is because when we do our `MethodPick`, we take the keys of what we are picking and get those methods.  But the flaw is **we haven't checked if those keys are required**.  `keyof Partial<All>` is `'A' | 'B' | 'C'`, so `type P = MethodPick<Partial<All>>` is A & B & C.  That means `SelectMethods<any>` is A & B & C where all three methods are required.

```
MORE extends Record<string, SelectMethods<any>>
```

So the above statement means that the values of this record must extend `All`, not `Partial<All>`. And that's not what we want.

If we already know that `METHODS extends Partial<All>`, why do we need to `Pick` at all?

We simplify the type to just  `= METHODS & MORE` and we replace `SelectMethods<any>` with `SelectMethods<Partial<All>>` since `any` isn't really a valid input and we get this:

```
type SelectMethods<
    METHODS extends Partial<All>, 
    MORE extends Record<string, SelectMethods<Partial<All>>> = {}
> = METHODS & MORE;
```

This should resolve your issues.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm7QCgEoAuZANwHtgATAbiwF8stRJZEUAhTHPTo0pRr0mLcNHhJkAYR54ZA8lTqNmYAJ4AHFKgA2u5AF40yAGTJu56fSwbtyAMoRdEBGACyEMAAsK1AM4APLy47gCiACoAEgDyACIOyBAAHpAgAcgACnBQYMBwuoF6ugB8ADTIIcjuMQBKYUmpEOn%20yLWuFFDUgf5gUKAA5hVOLm6ePn5B2bn5hcUlC0aYTCVL4dHxieY19Ta2WijjvtSZwAgA1oHrsQmNaRnTeQVF%20ovGpxcvuhVhqVCIYEC5wg6goMDQ%20gqwNB4OumwWagOaG4xiOfg%20l3Q5k4JUR9kyay8xwxgUesy%20CP29kSxhGrg8RMmpJyTzmr1xVMOnRQxnaCE63V6-RAQ0cznpaICzJmz3mlP5IF6yAAttzSO5uUtsPJkqRtfI8KgiHIDbgGGUqvJ%20IQTaamPImEwFUqKAAjABWAEZSHSxoypViLBUMMhdWLRgyJgGzBYY9JVgxVsZ9bgjTaU8hzVVrbbMxadXrLYbjRmHfnTRYS0WzeXTdIqxXM1VHTZnWBkG73QAmH3iv1RoKBzjB0O9iOSwcxnGZpOYXAAennWSgFG0uXUyAA5NJN8hgK1lfv-IM9yBkHYUJuScUKgAiVC35AAH2Qt84t5Ku9dAFd21AIAAjt%20wD-tQp7nkiV5nJikKvg%20z6vu%20CG3tIH6bgAdFUaa5lmVoNnguF4GGpbFum1Z5uROYkWazaMLQQA)